# OpenShift-Job to copy data from sftp to persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I would like to deploy a job which copies multiple files from sftp to a persistent volume and then completes.
My current version of this job looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: init-pv
        image: w0wka91/ubuntu-sshpass
        command: ["sshpass -p $PASSWORD scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 22 -r user@sftp.mydomain.com:/RESSOURCES/* /mnt/myvolume"]
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /mnt/myvolume
            name: myvolume
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: ftp-secrets
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: myvolume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myvolume
  backoffLimit: 3
```

When I deploy the job, the pod starts but it always fails to create the container:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWORD scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 22 -r user@sftp.mydomain.com:/RESSOURCES/* /mnt/myvolume: no such file or directory
```

It seems like the command gets executed before the volume is mounted but I couldnt find any documentation about it.
When I debug the pod and execute the command manually it all works fine so the command is definetely working.
Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The volume mount is incorrect, change it to:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /mnt/myvolume
  name: myvolume
```

Comment: Good catch. But it was just a mistake i made because i tried to anonymize the manifest. I just fixed that, thanks